# This regular expression breaks on safari but works in Google Chrome, how do I make it work in both

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, safari

I have a regex:

```
var regex = /(layout)(^|\s*)((?<!=)=(?!=))(^|\s*)/;
```

This works on Google Chrome but not on Safari and neither on Internet Explorer.
On Safari, the error is:

***`"Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name"`***

How can I fix this, please?

**UPDATE**
I have an xml input on which I run some checks before giving it to the xml parser. One of the checks is that I use string parsing to extract the layout name on included file names.

I try to identify whitespaces on the 'layout' attribute and clean it up e.g.

```xml
<Container
width="match_parent"
height="wrap_content">

<include
width="20px"
height="30px"
layout  =   "subcontent.xml"
/>
</Container>
```

would be changed to

```xml
<Container
width="match_parent"
height="wrap_content">

<include
width="20px"
height="30px"
layout="subcontent.xml"
/>

</Container>
```

I do this using a String.replace, then I extract the included file name and load it from storage and queue it for parsing also.

So think:

```
let check = 'layout=';

//change layout[space....]=[space.....] to layout=
let regex = /(layout)(^|\s*)((?<!=)=(?!=))(^|\s*)/;
xml = xml.replace(regex, check);
```

I hope its clearer now.

Comment: This looks rather convoluted. Do you want `var regex = /layout\s*=(?!=)\s*/;`?

Comment: Thanks so much for asking.
Would it do same thing?
I am parsing some xml(similar to android xml layouts) and one of the attributes look like: layout="kkk", I want to validate away all whitespace in between the `layout` and the `=` and in between the `=` and the "kkk".

Comment: I think the \s* after the /layout will still allow for whitespace in between, though. I dont want that behaviour

Comment: What do you mean by "validate away whitespace"? What is the real input? What is expected output?

Comment: I want to force the user to enter:  layout="xyz" , but not: layout = "xyz" or layout= "xyz", No whitespaces before the equals sign and after the equals sign

Comment: Why would you even force the user to input `layout=` instead of just the value?

Comment: Because its an xml attribute...e.g. <View color="red" layout="xxx.xml"/> I am doing some pre-processing or checks before the xml parser itself kicks in

Comment: Why do you use this `(^|\s*)` twice? The `^` case is not possible at both positions.

Comment: Why not `/layout="[your character group]+"/`, e.g. `/layout="[^"]+"/`?

Comment: When I detect the offensive pattern, I do a replace, so I cant use that...e.g. let check = 'layout='; let regex = /(layout)(^|\s*)((?<!=)=(?!=))(^|\s*)/;
 xml = xml.replace(regex, check);

Comment: Could you add a description of the expected behavior? It seems like a not working regular expression is not enough to understand the problem.

Comment: Alright let me edit

Comment: @jabaa, I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
let check = 'layout=';
let xml = "change layout    =   ";
let regex = /layout\s*=(?!=)\s*/g;
xml = xml.replace(regex, check);
console.log(xml)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/wYkTnz/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
"layout" - matches the characters layout literally (case sensitive)
"\s*" matches any whitespace character between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"=" - matches the character = with index 6110 (3D16 or 758) literally
 - Negative Lookahead "(?!=)":
   Assert that the Regex below does not match
    "=" - matches the character = with index 6110 (3D16 or 758) literally
"\s*" - matches any whitespace character between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```